# How can i fix my problem with raw folder in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to do my first Android app but i've a problem.
I've created in the res folder  the raw folder (res->New->Directory), my problem is that when i go into the code and i write R.raw the raw word appear red (raw folder isn't reconized).
How can i fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create the raw folder, follow step by step

```
res -> new -> Android Resource Directory -> Resource Type -> Select Raw -> Ok
```

Comment: Raw folder is empty?

Comment: actually yes, it's empty

Comment: You should add any files then try again.